# Android list view: scrolling resizes the items in a weird way

Tags: android, resize, listviewitem, android-listview

I have a problem with the list view and its items. When scrolling up/down the listview I noticed that the items slightly resize(about one pixel) and in my application it looks like **^**. The divider between two items should be one pixel high(used default android behavior), but when scrolling the divider is sometimes 2 pixels or 0 pixels(not visible). This is bad since it looks like the two items form one list item.

Has anyone a solution for this weird resizing problem when scrolling inside a listview?

My development device is the HTC Wildfire with firmware version 2.1-update1. Emulator is set to:Android 2.1-update1, skin WVGA800 and hw.lcd.density=240.

The ListView is filled with the following item layout and I used default settings for the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:background="#F0F0F0">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_icon"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testTextView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/test_icon"
        android:text="test"
        android:textColor="#555555" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen on both the emulator and real device?

Comment: yes it happens to me on both the emulator and device

Answer (score 1):

Try setting android:gravity to center|fill either on the outer element or both internal ones. This fixed a resize-while-scrolling problem I was having.

Comment: This could help. Next time i try your answer, since my project has ended. I ended up creating a workaround for it by placing my own divider image or strok of atleast 2px inside each cell. This ensures that the divider is always at least 1px. The calculations inside the android sdk sometimes end up below 1 pixel and while converting them to real pixels they get lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the text item to be `width="wrap_content"`